# Converting Flat file to List which is a property of another class

Tags: c#, file, reflection, deserialization, flat

```
public class DummyResponse
{
    public int UpdatedRecords { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public bool Isvalid { get; set; }
}

public class Request
{
    public List<DummyResponse> Changes { get; set; }
    public string ReuestedBy { get; set; }

    public Request()
    {
        Changes = new List<DummyResponse>();
    }
}
```

I have a flat file which contains tab separated data for Dummy Response.
I want this to be serialized to Request object.
The implementation needs should be generic as in  I only need  user to pass T (Request) in this case and identify the correct sub type to be filled from flat file.

I have below Code to convert it into Object. How ever its only working for properties having string type.

```
interface ICollectionBuilder
{
    object Build(IList dictionaries);
}

internal class CollectionBuilder<T> : ICollectionBuilder where T : new()
{
    public object Build(IList dictionaries)
    {
        var dictConverter = new DictionaryConerter<T>();
        return dictionaries
            .OfType<IDictionary<string, object>>()
            .Select(dict => dictConverter.ConvertTyped(dict))
            .ToList();
    }
}

interface IDictionaryConverter
{
    object Convert(IDictionary<string, object> dict);
}

internal class DictionaryConerter<T> : IDictionaryConverter where T : new()
{
    public object Convert(IDictionary<string, object> dict)
    {
        return ConvertTyped(dict);
    }

    public T ConvertTyped(IDictionary<string, object> dict)
    {
        T t = new T();
        var properties = t.GetType().GetProperties();

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> curr in dict)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(curr.Key)) continue;
            if (curr.Value == null) continue;

            Type valType = null;
            Type newType = null;
            PropertyInfo currProperty = null;
            foreach (PropertyInfo p in properties)
            {
                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(p.Name)) continue;

                if (String.Compare(p.Name.ToLower(), curr.Key.ToLower()) == 0)
                {
                    valType = t.GetType().GetProperty(p.Name).PropertyType;
                    newType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(valType) ?? valType;
                    currProperty = p;
                    break;
                }
            }
            object newVal = curr.Value;

            var curDict = curr.Value as IDictionary<string, object>;
            var curList = curr.Value as IList;
            if (curDict != null && newType.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes) != null)
            {
                newVal = ((IDictionaryConverter)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(DictionaryConerter<>).MakeGenericType(newType))).Convert(curDict);
            }
            else if (
                curList != null &&
                curList.OfType<IDictionary<string, object>>().Any() &&
                newType.IsGenericType &&
                newType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(List<>) &&
                newType.GetGenericArguments()[0].GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes) != null)
            {
                newVal = ((ICollectionBuilder)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(CollectionBuilder<>).MakeGenericType(newType.GetGenericArguments()[0]))).Build(curList);
            }

            t.GetType().GetProperty(currProperty.Name).SetValue(t, newVal);
        }

        return t;
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
void Main ()
    {
        var dict = new Dictionary<string,object>();
        dict.Add("ReuestedBy",abc);
        var innerDict = new Dictionary<string,object>();
        var list = new LIst<Dictionary<string,object>>();
        innerDict.Add("UpdatedRecords","45");
        innerDict.Add("Id","1");
        innerDict.Add("IsValid","False");
        dict.Add("Changes",list )
    }
```

The problem here is it  not working for any other type other than string.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it using below code while setting value

```
                propertyVal = Convert.ChangeType(propertyVal, targetType);
                propertyInfo.SetValue(inputObject, propertyVal, null);
```